# On Windows 2008 application crashes instead of handling the exception

Tags: c#, com, windows-server-2008

I have a function which should check, if COM is registered in the system. It may happen, that COM is registered, but dll file is missing - in this case function also should return false. MessageBoxes are only for debugging purposes:

```
public bool IsCOMInstalled(string name)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("?");
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(name));
        MessageBox.Show("!");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

On Windows XP and 7 above works fine. On Windows Server 2008, exception is not handled. Application crashes right after showing "?".

Why is that? How can I make my application handle an exception...?

Comment: I believe we need that `name`.

Comment: Well, it's TestDll.TestTools. I can't see how that would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug in TestDLL.TestTools on initialization.  If something causes the process to crash, it's not something you can catch like that.

Comment: Also, these ExecutionEngineException, StackOverflowException, and OutOfMemoryException won't be caught in the catch block, your app will just die.  But since you're doing a COM call, first check for missing native DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the problem with your framework of windows.

when Framework fail to handle exception that time CLR fail to run further. means your code totally destroys the functionality of CLR.

check the system requirements of windows 8 as maintained in Note of following link.
i found the system requirements for windows 8 to run this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx